# 1. The parameter @s_id has no default value 2. Invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, parameters

So my first problem starts when I load my values from my `datagridview` to my *textbox* and click *delete*, an error occurs saying that:

`the parameter @id has no default value`

Secondly, when I load my values again from my `datagridview` to my textbox and click update, an error occurs saying:

```
Invalid SQL statement
```

sorry. I'm just a newbie in regards with `visual basic`. I'm using access as my data base. Can someone care to explain and provide a solution? I'm sorry.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Public sEditType As String = String.Empty


Private Sub Save_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    Dim inputOk As Boolean = False

    Do Until inputOk = True

        Try
            'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
            conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            'I just use the textbox tag property to idetify if the data is new or existing.
            If Me.tbFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
                sSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_test ( first_namedb, last_namedb)"
                sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES(@first_namedb, @last_namedb)"
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL


            End If
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@first_namedb", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.tbFirstName.Text)) > 0, Me.tbFirstName.Text, DBNull.Value)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_namedb", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.tbLastName.Text)) > 0, Me.tbLastName.Text, DBNull.Value)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.tbFirstName.Tag
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If Me.tbFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
                cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                'Set textbox tag property with the ID of new record
                Me.tbFirstName.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            End If

            MsgBox("Data has been save.")
            inputOk = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)

        End Try
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Delete_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty


    Try
        'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.CommandText = "delete from tbl_test where student_ID = @s_id"

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.tbFirstName.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Data has been deleted.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        'I just use the textbox tag property to idetify if the data is new or existing.
        If Me.tbFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
            sSQL = "UDPATE tbl_test set first_namedb = @first_namedb, last_namedb = @last_namedb where student_ID = @s_id"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@first_namedb", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.tbFirstName.Text)) > 0, Me.tbFirstName.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_namedb", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.tbLastName.Text)) > 0, Me.tbLastName.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.tbFirstName.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Data has been updated.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Set_Button(ByVal iMode As Short)
    Select Case iMode
        Case 1

        Case 2

        Case 3

    End Select

End Sub
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim res As New DialogResult

    res = MsgBox("Do you want to save data?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample")
    If res = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Save_Record()
        'Set_Button(2)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    'Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable

    conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    conn.Open()
    'cmd.Connection = conn
    'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    sSQL = "Select * from tbl_test"
    'cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    'da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt


End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    tbFirstName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value
    tbLastName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value

End Sub




Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Update_Record()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Delete_Record()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Might be related : `UDPATE INTO tbl_test set ...` must just be `UPDATE tbl_test set ...`

Comment: thank you for the fast response kind sir. whoah that was a minor mistake. changed it but still, the error still occurs? any ideas sir?

Comment: your SaveRecord proc will ADD or UPDATE, but you also have an explicit UpdateRecord proc - which one is the source of the error?  (the first one has some flaws, BTW).  Both have UPDATE INTO, make sure thats gone

Comment: the save and load buttons work fine. im just having troubles with my update and delete button. i deleted the update in my save record (silly me, lol that was stupid of me). then what do you consider sir? sorry. a code would so i can understand better. thank you for helping sir

Answer (score 0):

Your delete procedure is missing a step:

```
cmd.CommandText = "delete from tbl_test where student_ID = @s_id"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@s_id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.tbFirstName.Tag
```

If `Me.tbFirstName.Tag` is 0, Null or Nothing you'll get the `no default value` error because you did not specify a valid ID and the related column has no default value.

Not sure your update problem is answerable because the related code seems not to be there, and SO likes but one question per post.